# Send mail from EC2 or EMR on AWS

Tags: email, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

**Is there any way to Send mails with Reports attached from EMR?**
I am using Amazon Web Services. I don't want to write a script inside EC2 to fetch data from EMR, add it on cron, then send the mails daily. Any luck, there is already any Jobs Scheduler from Amazon to automate this?

**Problem:**

- Implement daily job to generate .csv/.xls files on top of Hive
- Send the report in email

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AWS Data pipeline (and use EMR as a node inside it), it has OnSuccees and OnFailure alarm support. In the alarm you can configure to send email to you. 
http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/faqs/ (look for "How do I add alarms to an activity?").

You cant but customize the email content. May be you can keep the CSVs in a predesignated location with some time/date based naming convention. This way when you get the success mail, you know where to look into for the record.

All this you can do without writing any extra code (just configurations).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to setup Oozie in your EMR cluster and create a workflow that sends email through Amazon SES.

You can read up more on Oozie on their open source page:

https://oozie.apache.org/

You might find this helpful too:

https://github.com/lila/emr-oozie-sample

and finally Amazon SES:

http://aws.amazon.com/ses/